# Парсинг json файла в excel таблицу python

Tags: python, json, excel

Есть json файл, у каждой записи есть свой `id`. В каждой записи есть много `title` (много `title` принадлежат одному `id`). Как делать так, чтобы к одному `id` цеплять все его `title` из json файла. Данные должны отобразиться в excel таблице.
Есть код который может заносить в excel таблицу `id` или `title` отдельно. Не совсем понимаю как это делается

```py
import ijson
import xlsxwriter
from collections import defaultdict

//Создаю excel файл
workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('main.xlsx')
worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()

//Даю имена двум столбцам
worksheet.write(0, 0, 'ID')
worksheet.write(0, 1, 'title')

//Читаю json файл
f = open("sanya.json", 'r', encoding="utf8")

//Произвожу запись id из json файла в excel
'''
i = 1
for n in ijson.items(f, "item._id.$oid"):
    worksheet.write(i, 0, n)
    i += 1
'''
//Произвожу запись title из json файла в excel
j = 1
for k in ijson.items(f, "item.methods.item.subcategories.item.title"):
    worksheet.write(j, 1, k)
    j +=1
workbook.close()
```

Как уже написал, сейчас могу заносить либо только `id`, либо только `title`, а хотелось все и сразу
Как пример сейчас вывожу `title`, и 10 из них принадлежат одному `id`.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Код ошибки для [первой ревизии ответа](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/revisions/1515726/1), где join ругался на уже существующие колонки:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\ROG\Desktop\new_script_python\main.py", line 12, in <module>
    df = df.join(df_x[['name_title', 'name_recordId']].rename(columns={'name_title': 'title'}))
  File "C:\Users\ROG\Desktop\new_script_python\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 9734, in join
    return self._join_compat(
  File "C:\Users\ROG\Desktop\new_script_python\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 9773, in _join_compat
    return merge(
  File "C:\Users\ROG\Desktop\new_script_python\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\reshape\merge.py", line 158, in merge
    return op.get_result(copy=copy)
  File "C:\Users\ROG\Desktop\new_script_python\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\reshape\merge.py", line 807, in get_result
    result = self._reindex_and_concat(
  File "C:\Users\ROG\Desktop\new_script_python\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\reshape\merge.py", line 759, in _reindex_and_concat
    llabels, rlabels = _items_overlap_with_suffix(
  File "C:\Users\ROG\Desktop\new_script_python\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\reshape\merge.py", line 2572, in _items_overlap_with_suffix
    raise ValueError(f"columns overlap but no suffix specified: {to_rename}")
ValueError: columns overlap but no suffix specified: Index(['title', 'name_recordId'], dtype='object')
```

Переход между `id` в `json` файле

```
...
"name": "Муниципальный земельный контроль",
  "recordId": "0af4cd2e-78cb-109b-8178-e981366403f4",
  "status": "NOT_MODERATION_PUBLISHED",
  "slug": "2307"
},{
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "61c49773d06bd238714e7805"
  },...
```

Код новой ошибки

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\ROG\Desktop\new_script_python\main.py", line 8, in <module>
    df_x = pd.json_normalize(row.methods, record_path=['subcategories'], record_prefix='name_')
  File "C:\Users\ROG\Desktop\new_script_python\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\json\_normalize.py", line 447, in json_normalize
    raise NotImplementedError
NotImplementedError
```

Comment: что получается сейчас и что хочется получить?

Comment: а можно часть файла sanya.json для тестирования?

Comment: Хотел чтобы выводилась id, к нему указывались все title. Добавил скрин как есть выше

Comment: Добавил 1 запись из json файла для примера

Comment: @Salvador, у меня все title выводит в одну ячейку ,а в поле id - 61c49773d06bd238714e7809 или же для каждой строки title должно быть id и не важно, что id одинаковый ?

Comment: Используйте рекурсивный обход json с конечным случаем - следующим "_id".

Comment: Интересно как это запихнуть в таблицу и что вы подразумеваете под id и title. Тут довольно просто собирается таблица из `_id.$oid`, `name`, `recordId`, `status` и `slug`. А вот то что в methods лежит — многоуровневая табличка методов для данного id, которую логичнее было бы писать на отдельный лист с ссылкой на запись, как это делается в реляционных базах данных.

Answer (score 1):

Задача решается буквально в несколько строк с [pandas](/questions/tagged/pandas).
Получим первичную табличку через [`pd.json_normalize()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.json_normalize.html#pandas-json-normalize), прекрасной функцией для работы c json данными и преобразованием их в табличный формат.

```python
import json
import pandas as pd
with open('sanya.json', 'r') as f:
    data = json.load(f)
df = pd.json_normalize(data)
print(df)
```

###### Вывод:

```
                                             methods                                            name                              recordId                    status  slug                  _id.$oid
0  [{'category': ['Профилактические мероприятия']...  Муниципальный контроль в сфере благоустройства  0af4cd2e-78cb-109b-8178-e98136ad03fc  NOT_MODERATION_PUBLISHED  2311  61c49773d06bd238714e7809
```

В целом можно сказать, что результат чудесен. Ну правда неплох, обработалось вложение `_id` ⇛ `$oid`, всё остальное у нас находится на первом уровне, кроме **methods**. Там творится полный бардак, очень много списков, вложенных словарей и т.д. Раскрывать это даже в рекурсии мартышкин труд, но в целом можно сделать из этого реляционную БД, желательно не в Excel.

Ладно, если я правильно понял ваш [скриншот](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MTboA.png) в вопросе, вы хотите забрать первый уровень, а также **title** и **record_id** из **subcategories**, которому вы почему-то поставили префикс **name_**.

Будем придерживаться данной концепции, поехали:

1. `df.set_index('_id.$oid')`:
   Ставим ID на место индекса, по не нему потом будем делать join.
2. [`df[['methods']].iterrows()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iterrows.html#pandas-dataframe-iterrows) цикл:
   Идём по всем строкам по колонке **methods**, ведь их у вас в json будет больше, и:

   - берём `row.methods`, колонка из которой надо достать наш бардак, сразу идём в `subcategories` т.к. искомые колонки находятся там и делаем префикс **name_** как на скриншоте. Т.к. колонки `recordId` повторяются, префикс крайне необходим.
   - ставим индекс из `iterrows()`, т.е. строчка с которой работаем в цикле
   - делаем [`.join()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.join.html#pandas-dataframe-join) по индексу, тут не надо переживать, что мы добавим в искомый `df` новые строчки и несколько раз по ним пройдёмся, нет, `iterrows()` создаёт копию в памяти, так что на нём изменения не отразятся
     Тут же меняем **titile** с перфиксом на обычный.
   - дальше `if` и то что я изначально забыл, мы обсудили в комментариях. Для первого раза `join` отработает отлично, для последующих колонки уже будут в `df`, новые добавятся с суффиксом, чтобы не было конфликта.

     - если лишние есть (второй и последующие разы), собираем всё в одну колонку и убираем созданные лишние
     - `else` если проходимся первый раз, то уберём из `df` колонку **methods**, чтобы немного сэкономить память. Как мы помним она так и так останется в `iterrows`
3. Делаем фильтр по колонкам, тем самым убираем ненужные и сортируем
4. Пишем в excel.

```python
df = df.set_index('_id.$oid')
for ix, row in df[['methods']].iterrows():
    df_x = pd.json_normalize(row.methods, record_path=['subcategories'], record_prefix='name_')
    df_x.index = [ix] * len(df_x)
    df = df.join(df_x[['name_title', 'name_recordId']].rename(columns={'name_title': 'title'}), rsuffix='_right')
    if 'title_right' in df.columns:
        for i in range(2):
            df.iloc[:,-4+i] = df.iloc[:,-4+i].fillna(df.iloc[:,-2+i])
        df = df.iloc[:,:-2]
    else:
        df = df.drop(columns=['methods'])

df = df[['title', 'recordId', 'name', 'name_recordId', 'status', 'slug']]
df.index.names = ['ID']
df.to_excel("main.xlsx")
```

###### Выввод:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Спасибо за данный ответ и пояснения к нему, если не затруднит оставьте пожалуйста полный код

Comment: @Salvador просто копируйте первую и вторую часть, это полный код разделённый на два блока.

Comment: понял, большое спасибо

Comment: т.к. у меня `json` файл состоит из 30 тысяч записей, код выдает ошибку
```
Traceback (most recent call last):
df = df.join(df_x[['name_title', 'name_recordId']].rename(columns={'name_title': 'title'}))
```
Подскажите пожалуйста, как ее будет правильно исправить

Comment: @Salvador добавьте полностью ошибку в вопрос. Не понятно в чём там ошибка.

Comment: добавил полную ошибку в вопрос

Comment: может ли данная ошибка быть связана с тем, как отделены `id` в `json` файле? Добавил данный переход к вопросу

Comment: @Salvador нет, это просто я не предусмотрел, что будут одинаковые колонки при следующем `.join()`. Как дополню ответ, напишу.

Comment: @Salvador обновил ответ и объяснение. Логика может показаться немного костыльной, наверное оно так и есть, но отработать теперь должно без ошибок.

Comment: все равно выдает ошибку, только уже новую, указал ее в вопросе

Comment: @Salvador Не может быть такого, что раньше он у вас этот этап прошёл, а теперь нет. Значит json у вас изменился и [кривоват](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68864871/why-does-pandas-json-normalizejson-results-raise-a-notimplementederror) или неоднороден, и где-то subcategories нет. Ставьте try / catch и пропускайте или смотрите что творится с вложениями, без полного файла я вам уже ничем не помогу.

Comment: последний вопрос, ошибка возможно вызвана тем, что в subcategories не у всех title есть recordId. Как избежать этого, чтобы просто записывал пустоту?

Comment: @Salvador так просто в try / catch обернуть :) Но лучше разобраться почему их нет.

Comment: а что нужно указать в `except` когда вы в первый раз упомянули try/catch (когда я писал про вторую ошибку). Я добавил `try`, а в `except` просто указал print("error"). Файл обработался, но по ощущениям скрипт что-то пропустил и где-то не указал все `title` и их `recordId` (то есть просто пропуски в excel таблице, хотя в файле все записано норм), где-то просто не проходил по `title`

Comment: @Salvador я предполагал просто `pass`, а там по IDшникам в одну строчку можете посмотреть что в JSON творится. Я не могу предположить, что там отсутствует, но судя по ошибке, отсутствует весь `subcategories`, иначе бы ошибка была позже, так что `pass` не самый плохой вариант. По хорошему надо выводить ошибку и смотреть каждый конкретный случай.

Comment: мне кажется этим df = df.drop(columns=['methods']) удаляется что-то нужное

Comment: @Salvador можете закомментировать, не повлияет ни на что в цикле. Да и после тоже, т.к. фильтр, просто экономия памяти, как и написано в ответе.

Answer (score 0):

```
import ijson
import xlsxwriter
from collections import defaultdict

# Создаю excel файл
workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('main.xlsx')
worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()

# Даю имена двум столбцам
worksheet.write(0, 0, 'ID')
worksheet.write(0, 1, 'title')

# Функция для записи titles, используя рекурсию
def write_titles(id, titles, row):
    if not titles:
        worksheet.write(row, 0, id)
        worksheet.write(row, 1, '')
        return row
    title = titles[0]
    worksheet.write(row, 0, id)
    worksheet.write(row, 1, title)
    row += 1
    return write_titles(id, titles[1:], row)

# Читаю json файл
with open("sanya.json", 'r', encoding="utf8") as f:
    id_to_titles = defaultdict(list)
    for item in ijson.items(f, "item"):
        if not isinstance(item, dict):
            continue
        id = item.get('_id', {}).get('$oid')
        if not id:
            continue
        titles = []
        for method in item.get('methods', []):
            if not isinstance(method, dict):
                continue
            subcategories = method.get('subcategories', [])
            for subcategory in subcategories:
                if not isinstance(subcategory, dict):
                    continue
                title = subcategory.get('title')
                if title:
                    titles.append(title)
        id_to_titles[id].extend(titles)

# Произвожу запись id и titles из json файла в excel, используя функцию write_titles
row = 1
for id, titles in id_to_titles.items():
    row = write_titles(id, titles, row)

# Закрываем excel файл
workbook.close()
```

Comment: Запускаю ваш код, чтобы наверняка и получаю такую ошибку: titles = [subcategory['title'] for method in item['methods'] for subcategory in method['subcategories']]
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable

Comment: @Salvador, Эта ошибка означает, что в некоторых элементах JSON-файла отсутствуют значения, которые мы ожидаем. Чтобы предотвратить возникновение этой ошибки, можно добавить проверки наличия ключей и значений в каждом элементе. + подправил код

Comment: А если мне нужно чтобы если у меня нет какого-то значения он мне так и вывел в excel пустую строчку, тоже нужно проверку добавлять?

Comment: @Salvador, у Вас поле title бывает пустым ?

Comment: Я так понимаю он жалуется на `method`, что он типо пустой, хотя мы просто копаем дальше?

Comment: @Salvador , именно , я подправил код , попробуйте сейчас , у меня все пишет )

Comment: а в какой среде вы работаете?

Comment: @Salvador, в pycharm

Comment: Ваш код заполняет только ID и title, остальных колонок нет

Comment: @DiMithras, по условию нужно было только ID и title, остальные графы в цель вопроса не входили